# Building a SQL to calculate the number of rows relating to the parent

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql5

I am finding it hard to build a SQL, on the following database schema,

#### Shop

id
name

#### Order

id
shop_id
date
amount

You can see that a shop can have many orders.
I would like to a build a SQL that gives the number of orders of each shop on a specific date.
So the WHERE part must be (e.g. 2011-7-13),

WHERE order.date = '2011-7-13'

I can't think of how the SELECT part should be like. I think COUNT(*) should be used but this is all what I have got in my brain now.

Could somebody please give some hints on this?

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: As a recommendation - avoid using SQL reserved words for table/column names, even if your DBMS allows it, just to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Shop.name, COUNT(*) AS Num_Orders
FROM Shop JOIN `Order` ON Shop.id = `Order`.id
WHERE DATE(`Order`.`date`) = '2011-7-13'
GROUP BY `Order`.id;
```

Note, in case `date` is a `DATETIME` column I used the `DATE()` function to return only the date part of it, not the time.

You'll probably have to quote `date` and `Order` in backquotes as above, since they're reserved MySQL keywords.  Maybe not `date` but almost certainly `Order`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(1) AS order_count
  FROM Shop a INNER JOIN Order b
    ON a.id = b.shop_id
 WHERE `date` = '2011-7-13'
 GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Order.id), Shop.name, Order.date
FROM Shop INNER JOIN Order ON Shop.id=Order.shop_id
WHERE Order.date = '$date'
GROUP BY Shop.name, Order.date
ORDER BY Order.date
```

I've included date in the results for verification.

Comment: Grouping by the name, when you've got a perfectly good `id` column to use (that's probably shorter, and **should** be indexed)?

Comment: Name is human-readable...why would you want to query the id only?  By the way, two other answers that were posted **after** mine seem to agree...

Comment: Hmm, true, didn't really think about that part...  And doing a rolled up table-refence may not be terribly performant.  Guess I'm too used to having CTEs to do this sort of work.

Answer (score 1):

After some consideration (and @AJ's well deserved remark), here's my (revised) answer.

```
SELECT shop.id, shop.name,
FROM shop
JOIN (SELECT shop_id, date, COUNT(*)
      FROM order
      WHERE date = :date
      GROUP BY shop_id, date) as order_count
ON order_count.shop_id = shop.id
```

If you want a list of all order counts by date, remove the inner `WHERE` clause.